# How to add a custom State for WorkItems in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services (http://visualstudio.com/), with Visual Studio 2012.

I'd like to add a new State Value for WorkItems. After a search I discover that i can edit the process template to achieve that. I've tried the menu item "Team\Team Project Collection Settings\Process Template manager", but i'm getting the following message:

> Visual Studio could not retrieve your user permissions from Team Foundation Server.
>
> Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator to determine the cause of the error and the steps to correct the problem.
>
> If the problem persists, contact Microsoft Product Support Services
>
> Details: Access Denied: marlon.brum@gmail.com needs the following permission(s) on the resource $ to perform this action: Administer

I've added my user to every adminstrator group i've found in tfs configuration, for the project and the collection, but i keep getting that message.

How can i add a custom state to WorkItems in Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please note that the UI of VSTS has recently been changed. I'm updating my answer to reflect the latest changes but keeping an older copy too!

Update: As of 17th Oct 2018, on Team Services:

1. Account Home - Click on the Azure DevOps icon in the upper left corner.
2. Organization Settings - Click on this link in the lower left corner
3. Process - Click on Process in Boards Group in the list of settings
4. Select your process
5. Select the Work Item Type you want add the new state to
6. Click on **States Menu** item on the top
7. Click **New State** button

*Adding a Gif below*

[image: Steps to add a custom State for WorkItems in Visual Studio Team Services - Update Team Services UI]

For those who are still on the older UI , on Team Services...

1. Account Home - Click on the team services icon in the upper left
   corner.
2. Process - Mouse over the Gear icon and choose Process
3. Choose the process you are working in
4. Click on Product Backlog Item type
5. Click on the States tab (between Layout and Rules)
6. Click the New State link

   - **Account Home** can be accessed by clicking on the **Azure DevOps** icon (previously **Team Service**) in the top-left corner. This page is also the home page of you account and can be accessed by directly jumping using the URL. For example: *youraccountname.visualstudio.com/*
   - **Process** can be accessed from the UI as mentioned in steps above or by using the direct URL *youraccountname.visualstudio.com/_settings/process*

Hope it helps!

Thanks Microsoft for making it available!

Comment: I can't find process in TFS 2017 @ http://srv-newtfs:8080/tfs/_admin?path=Programming&_a=node any other suggestions?

Comment: This is for Visual Studio Team Services. I can't validate that against TFS.

Comment: In TFS 2018, I can find the Process tab, but I see no UI for modifying them except to export them.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson - These steps are for the online hosted [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/] (Azure DevOps). From top of my head, in TFS, after you export the process, you need to manually edit the files or in pull them in Visual Studio to edit. Take a look at some docs here - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-wit?view=azure-devops] or [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019]. I have only seen people doing it that way. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

http://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs-2012-versions-of-team-foundation-server/

Cons: •Can’t customize process template or workitem templates

So it is not possible to add new states on Team Foundation Services.

Nevertheless, "Team\Team Project Collection Settings\Process Template manager" just allows you to up- and download Process Templates, where you can edit the WIT XMLs. A more comfortable way is to use/install TFS PowerTools and use the WIT Editor "Tools -> Process Editor -> Work Item Types -> Open WIT from Server/File".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried the TFS PowerTools, but got the same message. I guess i've to try what i want in a differente way.

Comment: I change the accepted answer because it is now possible to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is not supported by *Visual Studio Team Services*. It seems this is causing a lot of people (including myself) problems. [See here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online) for the (planned) feature request.

I suspect the reason for your permission error is not that you haven't assigned the right permission, but rather that the permission is not available to be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You need **Team foundation Server Admin rights** to execute witadmin tasks.
What probably you mean by following is that you have added yourself to default collection admin/project admin.

> I've added my user to every adminstrator group i've found in tfs configuration, for the project and the collection,

For that you have two options:

1. Either request your TFS admin to do this activity for you.
2. Request you TFS Admin to add you to the TFS Admin Group **using TFS Admin Console.**