# Adding to State Picklist in Azure DevOps Service

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps Service (the on-line version, not on-premise) with Agile methodology.

I'm trying to add a custom state of 'Testing'. I use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718150/how-to-add-a-custom-state-for-workitems-in-visual-studio-team-services), but this doesn't seem to work. I can add Testing as a column in the sprint board, but it doesn't appear in the State picklist values (I do understand that adding a column will not add a State).

How can I get this to appear in the State picklist?

Comment: Columns aren't states. States are **mapped** to columns. If you want to add a new state, edit the available states for the state field in the process template.

Comment: @DanielMann ... Yep ... I know, I was just showing that I looked around all the possibilities. Adding a column doesnt create a state. I'll amend my question so it is clearer to that point.

Comment: Also, you can't edit the state basic processes. Do you create the [inherited process from Agile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process)?

Comment: No, I Customised the workflow as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get this to appear in the State picklist?

1.You can quickly navigate to the process your current project belongs to via `Project settings => Overview => Project Details`.

[image]

Then you can modify the states there. If you want to add a `Testing` state to `Bug` WorkItem type, click the `Bug` and click the `new state`:

2.And we should know that only `inherited process` can be modified in this way. So we must make sure our project is created from [inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process). Otherwise the `New State` button is disabled.

Comment: can I ask what version of Azure DevOPs you are using? I don't have "Project settings => Overview => Project Details", The "Project Details" doesn't appear on the "Overview" screen. I think the Azure DevOps Service (online) is different to the Azure DevOps Server (on-premise)

Comment: @MarcusD Normally we don't need to talk about the version of online service, we only talk about the version of Azure Devops Server. Check if you can see the project details page above. And, does the original issue still persists to block you?

Comment: I can see the page you have inserted, but when I browse to the 'CustomProcess' in your example -> 'Tasks' -> State ... the '+New State' is greyed out, so I cant change it.

Comment: Also, I realise that version of online software is not very meaningful, I was making the distinction between the on-premise version and the online version.

Comment: @MarcusD For why the button `New State` is geryed out: 1. Make sure the process of your project is not basic processes. The basic processes like Basic, Agile, Scrum, and CMMI is not supported to edit. You need to create [inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process) from them, and the inherited processes is supported to modify.  2. Also, make sure you have the required permissions to do that. I'm the owner of the organization, so I can feel free to do that.

Comment: *inherited process* ... thank you for persisting with this. I've created an inherited process and modified it and now the extra state appears in the drop downs. Do you want to tweak your answer to make this small, but significant step clear?

Comment: @MarcusD Of course, answer updated~ Feel free to edit the answer if you want to improve it with more details. Also, if the answer helps to resolve your puzzle, please consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that more members with similar issue can easily find the useful info and we can archive this thread. Have a nice day :)